# Trouble with basic Javascript

Tags: javascript

I haven't touched Javascript in a while and now I'm having trouble with basic arrays.

```
params=new Array();
params['return']='json';
alert(params.length);
```

This always returns `0` when I'm expecting `1`. What's wrong with this?

Comment: Only numeric indices will affect the `.length` of an Array. You're using `params` as though it was a plain `Object`, and Objects don't have an automatic `.length`. To count them, you could do `Object.keys(params).length`

Comment: Arrays are not associative in JS...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays use numerical indexes. When you use a string "index", it just adds a new property to the array object, but the new value isn't in the array.

Thus, the array is still empty, but you can access your value as you could with any other object.

Your code is equivalent to

```
var params = {}; //new object (not array)
params['return']='json'; //new property added to object
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

You forgot `var`:

```
var params = new Array();
```

But an array takes numeric indices, so `params['return']` is not really a member of the array but of the object that represents the array, so it doesn't affect the length.

You could use an object but objects have no length:

```
var params = {};
params['return'] = 'json';
```

To get the length though you can count the keys in that object and get the length of the resulting array:

```
var len = Object.keys(params).length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript arrays don't hold key value pairs like objects do, so the length isn't incremented when you assign a value. They are however objects themselves, so you can assign values to its properties (in this case the `return` property).
You probably want params to be a plain object: `params = {}`

You need to count the properties, like this for example:

```
function dictionarySize(dict){
    var size = 0;
    for (key in dict){
        // In practice you'd probably want to filter using hasOwnProperty
        size++;
    }
    return size
}
alert(dictionarySize(params));
```

Or using a library like underscore.js:

```
_.size(params);
```

[`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) is also an option, although it won't work in IE8 and older.

If you don't need an key value pairs use params.push:

```
params=new Array();
params.push('json')
alert(params.length); // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array, push stuff on it, and assign properties to values of it like so:

```
var params=[];
params.push('firstly');
params[0]="jonson";
params['return']="fredy"
params.newone="json";
params.push('Carl');
```

NOW, if you do:

```
console.log(params.length,params);
```

the result of that is:

> 2 ["jonson", "Carl", return: "fredy", newone: "json"]

SO, you see "firstly" was replaced by "jonson" in the [0] - so the "pushed" value is addresed by the numerical `[0]`